# Replace part of a string with a variable or another string

Tags: javascript, string

I know that this has been asked many times before, but I am a complete beginner to JS and did not understand any of the answers, and they did not seem to work when I attempted to run said solutions. I would like to know how to replace a part of a string with a variable, or potentially another string.

So if my code looks like this:

```
var text = "Eam dicit fuisset volumus an, usu ea tibique consulatu scribentur.";
var otherString = "Random text";
```

...how can I replace the text.substring[9, 20] with otherString, for instance.

Please explain as much as you can.

Comment: `text.replace('string to replace', 'string to insert')` not good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = text.replace(text.substring(9, 20), otherString);
```

We are setting text, to the replaced text. I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: Hmm, works providing the string being searched for does not exist earlier in the text. In this case that cannot be the case but the warning remains pertinent in case the constants are changed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to your specific problem would be :

```
  text = text.slice (0,9) + otherString + text.slice (20);
```

Replace the value of variable `text` with the first 10 characters of `text` followed by the value of `otherString` followed by the part of `text` after the 20th character.